# Convert a parent class instance object to behave like a son class instance object

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

Suppose i have a class as follows:

```
private class ComparableElement extends Element implements Comparable<ComparableElement> {

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ComparableElement o) {
            return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
        }
    }
```

where Elements is defined as follows:

```
public class Element {

    protected String name;

    protected String category;

    public Element() {
        super();
    }

    public Element(String _name, String _category) {
        super();
        this.name = _name;
        this.category = _category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name; 
    }
}
```

Then in case i have an Element object, whats the best practice to convert that Element object to a ComparableElement instance? something like :

```
Element e;
...
ComparableElement ce = (ComparableElement)e;
```

only that this wouldnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new constractor `ComparableElement` :

```
public ComparableElement (Element element )
{

     //Here you get all the data from the element and set it to this object.

}
```